# Differences between "align" and "line"

Tags: orthography

Why is "align" not spelt "aline" or, conversly, why is "line" not spelt "lign".

(I hope I'm not out of lign by asking this.)

Answer (score 3):

Probably because of their etymology, according to which in  *align*  the French spelling  of *alignier*  remained,  while in *line* the old English usage of  *line* prevailed:

[Align](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=align):

> - early 15c., "to copulate" (of wolves, dogs), literally "to range (things) in a line," **from Middle French aligner, from Old French alignier** "set, lay in line," from à "to" (see ad-) + lignier "to line," from Latin lineare, from linea.

[Line](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=line&allowed_in_frame=0):

> - **a Middle English merger of Old English line "cable, rope; series, row, row of letters; rule, direction," and Old French ligne** "guideline, cord, string; lineage, descent;" both from Latin linea "linen thread, string, line," from phrase linea restis "linen cord," from fem. of lineus (adj.) "of linen," from linum.

(Etymonline)

Note  also the verb to  [aline](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/aline) ( to range or place in a line; to bring into line; to align) but it is very rare. (TFD)

As for [lign](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/lign-), it is a prefix that indicates wood (lignin, lignocellulose) from Latin *lignum*,  wood.